# Turning existing pages into a pivot page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have several xaml pages in a WP7 MVVM project. I want to take these pages and combine them together into a pivot page.

All the tutorials show how to begin with a pivot page but i am looking for an easy method without too much re-factoring to turn my pages into a pivot page

I already have ViewModels for my pages so i am wondering how a new Pivot page interact with it

Thanks

Comment: If the pages aren't using the app bar, I'd just create UserControls out of them. Then in each Pivot, put the UserControls. It's a good way to abstract away some of the code-behind that might get confusing next to a bunch of other pivot items. (and you COULD still use an AppBar and do this method, it's just a little bit of a pain and has somewhat ugly code for communicating with the controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a few lines in the xaml.

You'll need a reference to the silverlight toolkit (easy to obtain online).

```
<controls:Pivot Name="pivotControl">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Header1">
            <!--Page 1 here-->
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Header2">
            <!--Page 2 here-->
        </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Repeat as necessary.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: what about all the code behind my pages ? where do i put it now ?

Answer (score 1):

The way Ive done this in the past is to add a new pivot page to my solution. So, lets say you have 2 pages that you would like to add to a pivot page, you could add a new pivot page to your solution and then copy the content of each page into the pivot page into the appropriate section, such as:

```
   <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
                YOUR PAGE1 CONTENT HERE
            </controls:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
                YOUR PAGE2 CONTENT HERE
            </controls:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like Caliburn Micro it's as simple as adding your new pages' ViewModels to the main PageViewModels Items collection.

So in the MainPage.xaml

```
 <controls:Pivot x:Name="Items" />
```

and in MainPageViewModel:

```
 Items.Add(Page1ViewModel);
 Items.Add(Page2ViewModel);
 Items.Add(Page3ViewModel);
```